# jQuery Novice: how to remove certain child elements

Tags: jquery

I need to remove the 2nd and 3rd `<br>` elements in the parent `<address>` element such that the `City` and `StateCode` are on the same line. Here is the exact code:

```
<address>
    <label>3651 Stardust Drive</label>
    <br>
    <label>Hannibal</label>
    <br>
    <label>MO</label>
    <br>
    <label>63401</label>
</address>
```

I need to modify the HTML such that it reads as follows:

```
3651 Stardust Drive
Hannibal, MO
63401
```

The html I am having to work with is as it is because I am using jQuery Mobile with MVC. I know there are other ways to do this but would rather just write a jQuery function to fix it up for me.

I initially tried removing all the line breaks but I need to keep the first line break and keep the others....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     //pretty-up the address & job descriptions
       $('<br>').remove();
 });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Removing the second and third `<br>` elements does not produce the result you describe. You also forgot to post the code you tried.

Comment: Your description does not match your example.

Comment: I guess I just need to know how to say, "hey, remove only certain <br>'s, just not all of them like my code snippet above poorly illustrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> EDIT:
>
> > > I need to remove the 2nd and 3rd `br` elements in the parent `address` element
>
> You need to clarify this, as your example of what you want has the zipcode on a separate line. I took you literally, so my answer addresses the initial question you posed.

First, you would need to select the `br` elements correctly if you were going to directly select them:

`$('br')`

Instead, you wanted to remove all `br` elements except the first from the `address` element.

So, start from the address element and remove all of the `br` tags not equal to the first (element 0 within the list).

`$('address').find('br:not(:eq(0))').remove();`

See [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssLQx/)

If you need the comma added **to** the city label, that's as easy as selecting the appropriate label and then appending it, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/ssLQx/4/).

If you need the comma added **after** the city label, that's as easy as selecting the appropriate label and then adding it after, [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/ssLQx/5/). Which you pick depends on what else you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('<br>').remove();
```

This does not in fact remove any br element, as `$('<br>')` creates a new br element (not inserting it anywhere) and .remove() tries to remove it from the document (which does nothing).

To actually remove all br elements, you would need

```
$('br').remove();
```

in which `$('br')` looks for existing br elements in the document and .remove() removes them.

If you only want to remove br elements from a particular parent element or elements, you can either add to the `'br'` selector (e.g. changing it to `'address br'`), or you can use .find():

```
var $elems = $('address');
$elems.find('br').remove();
```

To pull the text out of the label elements, you can do something like

```
$elems.find('label').contents().unwrap();
```

You can find information about all the jQuery methods I used at http://api.jquery.org/.

Comment: Nice catch on the markup used instead of a selector, I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<br>').remove();
```

(Also the correct syntax to select the **br** is `$('br')` and not `$('<br>')`  )

```
$('<br>') creates a New br element
```

`$('br').remove()`  Removes all the br tags..

Try this instead

```
 $('address').find('br:eq(1)').remove();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/3RuYx/)**